# How to use SQLite database from one platform(iOS) to another(Windows)

Tags: c++, ios, database, sqlite, mfc

I don't know its a valid question or not.
I am working on one MFC/C++ application where

I want to use `SQLite` database from `iOS` application in my windows application.

My `iOS` database is encrypted using command `sqlite_key`.

While I am trying it for my windows application for the same database 
It throws an exception for any operation on the database.

While Searching on Google I am not able to get right track for this.

Can anyone tell me is it possible?

And if yes please help me on this.

Comment: I don't see how that would be directly possible. First, how is your iOS application connected to your windows application?

Comment: Actually, the database will be imported from dropbox and will be used in my application

Comment: The standard SQLite library does not support encryption. Which extensions are you using?

Comment: I am using `SQLiteEncrypt.dll`. refer from [SQliteEncrypt](http://www.sqlite-encrypt.com/sample-cpp.htm) Which has his own `api` to handle database.i.e `db->key()` which is using `sqlite_key()` function for this operation.

Comment: Is the key a character string or data bytes?

Answer (score 0):

If your plan is to "export" it, i.e you want to reuse the data inserted by your ios application into your windows one, then you simply need to locate on your iphone the sqlite database file (sqlite store everything in one single location) and copy it on your computer, and tell your windows software the location of this file.

If your is to "share" the database, i.e both should be able to modify it in "realtime", then you will have to roll something on your own, as Sqlite3 does not provide any network support, it's just a library to read and write data in a file, in a SQL way.

Comment: as database is encrypted with a key I have applied a same key to use it further but it is showing an exception.