# C++: How to reuse Encrypted Sqlite database in MFC application which is already in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, sqlite, encryption, mfc

I am in the middle of one project where I want to reuse `SQLite` database of `iOS` application in my `MFC\C++` application.

The `iOS` database is encrypted using 'sqlite3_key()' and it is using [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) for database handling.

And

I am using [SQLiteEncrypt](http://www.sqlite-encrypt.com/sample-cpp.htm) for databse handling with the help of [CppSQLite3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6343/CppSQLite-C-Wrapper-for-SQLite) Wrapper.

But when I am trying to execute any statement on database it throws and exception ***`File is encrypted or not a database`*** .

I not getting any lead on this.

Can any one help me out on this?

I know its duplicate of the following question but that questions are *Inactive* and I am not able to get any answer from that question.

1.[How to use SQLite database from one platform(iOS) to another(Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21084204/3110262)

2.[How to open and read SQLite database from another platform like (iOS to Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21185771/3110262)

Please Help me out on this.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite provides common interface for encryption, but the implementation of the encryption engine is delivered by individual vendors.

Encryption engines on the market are not compatible, you have to use the one that was used to encrypt the database.

Comment: Can you suggest any encryption engine which I can use?

Comment: You said yourself:

The iOS database is encrypted using 'sqlite3_key()' and it is using SQLCipher for database handling.

Comment: I have tried but it failed. after setting key I got exception on execution of next instruction

Comment: Also a `File is encrypted or not a database`? Where you following instructions from documentation? I mean have you used sqlite3_key() and **then** sqlite3_exec()?

Comment: yes I am following this too. Still on sqlite3_exec I am getting same exception

Comment: Well, then either encryption engine was different, or the password is different.

Comment: 1st may be possible but I am not able to trace it and abut password I am using password same as iOS

Comment: Some of SQLite encryption engines don't encrypt header. You can open the database file and see if it starts with "SQLite3......" string. SQLCipher **does** encrypt header. I'm not sure which other engines do encrypt header and which don't, but this may give you some hint. If you're able to execute any SQL query on the iOS (as you said you can read it there), then try executing: `PRAGMA cipher;` - this is unique pragma command implemented only in SQLCipher. If it works, it means you're dealing with SQLCipher. If not, you need to look for other engines and their "unique" features.

Comment: Yes I have checked for `PRAGMA cipher` and its clear that it is using SQLCipher

Comment: Maybe the database was encrypted with different major version of SQLCipher? If you're using SQLCipher 3.x.x, then take a look at http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#cipher_migrate - if it works, then you know this is SQLCipher 1 or 2.