# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_key referenced in function _main

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am working on one c++ project where I want to use `Sqlite` database but in my code I am getting error.

as **error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_key referenced in function _main**

I my code is:

```
sqlite3 *db;

int rc;
rc = sqlite3_open("sql.db", &db);
const char ch[] = "1234";

rc = sqlite3_key(db,ch,strlen(ch));

if (sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    printf("Success");
     // key is correct. 
 } else { 
     // key is incorrect
     printf("Error in Database Execution");
 }
```

I am using `VS2010`.
I did all the required settings of `lib` and `dll`.
But it does not help me so far.

Can any one help me out on this?

Comment: `sqlite3_key()` is not a part of standard sqlite so first make sure your linker path has the version of sqlite with this extension.

Comment: yes it has `sqlite3ext.h` but still giving same error

Comment: Header files `.h` are used when compiling. Libraries e.g. `.lib` are used when linking. You have a linker error.

Comment: @laalto Yes, you are right I have downloaded [DLL and LIB](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) but it does not help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using an encryption library like [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) or [SQLiteEncrypt](http://www.sqlite-encrypt.com/develop-guide.htm), which means you have to to add the corresponding library, for example `SQLiteEncrypt.lib` to the lib settings. You probably can also add use a `#pragma` instead.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "SQLiteEncrypt.lib")
```

Comment: sorry I am not using `SqliteEncrypt` Library because it does not help me for my further steps in application that`s why I am using `native sqlite3.dll and sqlite3.lib`

Comment: then remove the line containing `rc = sqlite3_key(db,ch,strlen(ch));` from your source

Comment: I can`t please take a look at [my next approach for my application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21251113/3110262)

Comment: If you use SQLCipher you have to use that library (I can't find it's name). But as you use `sqlite3_key` you are using an extension which is not part of the native sqlite3.dll and sqlite3.lib.